# jQuery calling Change Event with Trigger only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a dropdown filter which uses the change function. 
Now when I try this filter by directly changing the selected option it works fine, but when I try to change the selected value with URL-parameters, the display property (which gets dynamically changed in the filter-function) only changes for the first item found and all other items with the correct filtering-value do not get their property set to block.

This is the filter-function I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.customFilter select').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filterValue = $('#myDropdown').val();

        var filterSelector = '#container .filter-item' + '.' + filterValue);

        $('#jpagescontainer .photo-item').css('display','none');
        $(filterSelector).css('display','block');
    });
});
```

and here is my function for changing the selected value with URL-parameters:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cat = getUrlParameter('category');

    $('#myDropdown option[value=' + cat + ']').attr("selected", "selected");
    $('#myDropdown option[value=' + cat + ']').trigger('change');
});
```

The two filter-variables stay the same for both calls.

And my HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="customFilter">
    <select id="myDropdown" class="filter">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Show all</option>
        <option value="opt1">Option1</option>
        <option value="opt2">Option2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="filter-item opt1">
        <p>Some Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item opt2">
        <p>Some Text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything wrong with the URL function, or am I missing something?

## EDIT:

I pretty much figured it out thanks to the help of Mark Baijens ... the problem was caused by an additional script which limited the shown items to 20 and it just so happened that none but one of the first 20 items matched the filter category.

Comment: Where is your function `getUrlParameter()`?

Comment: Try calling the change event on the select box. The option element is not the one that is changing.

Comment: the `getUrlParameter()` function is implemented beforehand, and works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a bit unclear. There where some things wrong with your code. I think this is what you want. I escaped the `getUrlParameter` function because it doesn't work in snippets. I replaced this with the value with `opt1` to mimic the url function value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.customFilter select').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filterValue = $('#myDropdown').val();
        
        if(filterValue === '') {
            var filterSelector = '#container .filter-item';
        }
        else {
            var filterSelector = '#container .' + filterValue;
        }

        $('#container .filter-item').hide();
        $(filterSelector).show();
    });
    var cat = 'opt1'; //getUrlParameter('category');

    $('#myDropdown').val(cat);
    $('#myDropdown').trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.filter-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customFilter">
    <select id="myDropdown" class="filter">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Show all</option>
        <option value="opt1">Option1</option>
        <option value="opt2">Option2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="filter-item opt1">
        <p>Some Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item opt1">
        <p>Some Text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item opt2">
        <p>Some Text 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you have multiple values in the category of the url? And can you show what your url looks like?

Comment: The url looks like this: site.com/filterpage?category=opt1

Comment: yeah if the value is `opt1` in the url it will only show the opt1 div. You don't want that? Can please describe in detail the result you are expecting.

Comment: I'll try to be a bit more specific: If you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wspzhjmy/8 you can see that upon choosing Option1 it displays the two divs. But in my case, when I try this with said url-parameters, it will only display the first div, altough the second div also has the value=opt1

Comment: It's seems to work fine when i mimic the `opt1` value in my code snippet. Can you try `console.log(getUrlParameter('category'));` and see what value is returned by the function?

Comment: I checked and the returned value is opt1, if it wasn't then not even one item would show, right?

Comment: Yeah but it's strange since as you can see in my snippet i placed `opt1` on the same place where the function would put the value and it works as intended. You probably have some other code that you didn't post that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah I see too that when hardcoding the URL parameter in the snippet above it works ... I guess it really does come to the conclusion that another script may be the cause of the problem, even tough I do not have a clue as to which would have such an effect on it. I will keep you updated, thank you for your help.

Comment: Since it's only on the initial load it's probably in one of the `$(document).ready()` event handlers. Start looking there. A great way to do this is to escape all related code. If the problem doesn't happen anymore unescape peaces of code one by one till you find the problem. Good luck.